# how to lookup in mongoose after lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

> im wana lookup in mongoose

my question is how in mongoose can lookup in lookup value

example im have todos = [objectID] after lookup todos = [{owner:objectID, memebers:[objectID]}

im try this code but donst work

#### this my code

```
const userAggregate = await UserModel.aggregate([
        {
            $match:{
              $or:[{"_id":req.user._id}]
            },
            
        },
        {
          $lookup:{
            from:"todos",
            localField:"todos",
            foreignField:"_id",
            as:"todos"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup:{
            from:"users",
            localField:"owner",
            foreignField:"_id",
            as:"owner"
          }
        },

      ]);
```

#### this result

**my target is todos im want to lookup owner and members**

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "succsess": true,
    "user": {
        "_id": "647cdd81672d662c21e94780",
        "first_name": "XXXXXX",
        "last_name": "XXXXXXX",
        "password": "$2b$10$mznb1HCopfcvMvXchJzH6eaXIEiiFjosv430boVaiP7akbpylOsPq",
        "todos": [
            {
                "_id": "6484a24fea0553dbcb619c44",
                "owner": "6484a1f5ea0553dbcb619c2d",
                "title": "first reza task",
                "completed": false,
                "startAt": "2023-06-10T12:40:16.324Z",
                "members": [
                    "647cdd81672d662c21e94780"
                ],
       
            }
        ],
       
    }
}
```

im try this but dosnt work:

```
 const userAggregate = await UserModel.aggregate([
        {
            $match:{
              $or:[{"_id":req.user._id}]
            },
            
        },
        {
          $lookup:{
            from:"todos",
            localField:"todos",
            foreignField:"_id",
            as:"todos"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup:{
            from:"users",
            localField:"owner",
            foreignField:"_id",
            as:"owner"
          }
        },

      ]);
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data in Users collection and Todo Collection. And the structure of the response you are looking for.